# Naming style of stdio.h FILE

Tags: c, naming, stdio

In the C stdio library, why is the type FILE written as such from a coding style perspective?

If I look at stdio.h documentation, the file follows the following naming style:

- functions : lowercase
- MACROS : UPPERCASE
- CONSTANTS : UPPERCASE
- type_t : lowercase_t
- FILE : ?

I see other types written like size_t or uint32_t. Why does FILE break the rule?

Comment: "`type_t` : `lowercase_t`" You should be aware that the suffix `_t` is reserved by the POSIX standard.

Comment: @Rob Looking at stdio.h source, FILE is declared as : typedef struct __sFILE FILE

Comment: @Swordfish Good to know.

Comment: Note that there is also the type `DIR`, used by `opendir()` and friends.